# pg_upgrade are failing due to The source cluster lacks some required control information: latest checkpoint oldestXID error

Tags: windows, postgresql

```
C:\Users\ChemoLIMS Server>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_upgrade.exe" --old-bindir "C:\ChemoLIMS\data\bin" --new-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin" --old-datadir "C:\ChemoLIMS\data\data" --new-datadir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data" -U postgres
```

Output:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
The source cluster lacks some required control information:
  latest checkpoint oldestXID

Cannot continue without required control information, terminating
Failure, exiting
```

I'm hitting this type of error.

Comment: What is the old version?  What output does the old pg_controldata give?

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty new with PostgreSQL. May i know how to execute the pg_controldata?